# firebase cloud function how to get value and update it

Tags: android, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get a value from a place in my database add 1 to it and set it back but I'm getting different errors the latest  is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
at admin.database.ref.once.then (/user_code/lib/index.js:22:25)
```

not sure why its trying to read it as a property i thought it was a method? my entire method is this

```
admin.database().ref('users/' + senderId + '/contacts/' + recipientId)
.once('value').then((contactSnapshot) => {
    var mContact = contactSnapshot.val()
    let unread = mContact['unread']
    console.log('contact name is ' + mContact['user_name'] + ' unread count is ' + unread)
    unread++
    var contactReference = mContact.ref
    contactReference.update({'unread' : unread})
})
```

my console log prints fine with the contact name and the unread count I'm pretty useless at java script (this is actually type script) which i will be addressing any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mContact = contactSnapshot.val()` returns the raw javascript value of the location of the database that was queried.  It contains no other reference objects.  mContact will not have a `ref` property, unless you have a key value named `ref` in your database at that location.

It sounds like you want to `contactSnapshot.ref` instead.  Or just the remember the reference as you originally constructed it:

```
const contactReference = admin.database().ref('users/' + senderId + '/contacts/' + recipientId)
```

Comment: as i posted this i saw that this might be the case many thanks what i wanted was contactSnapshot.ref